# Slow linq query when looking for char(1) datatype using contains

Tags: entity-framework, char, contains

I've got an old database with a char(1) Status column. I'm using code first and entity framework 4.3.1 to interact with my database. My Status column in my code first class is defined as follows:

```
[Column(TypeName = "char")]
public string Status { get; set; }
```

I'm writing a linq query to fetch all items with a Status of one of several values. The code looks something like this (although it's been simplified):

```
List<string> statusList = new List<string>() {"N","H","P"};
...
var entries = (from t in context.MyTable where statusList.Conains(t.Status)).ToList();
...
```

The SQL thats generated prefixes all the Status values with N making the query quite slow.

```
WHERE ([Extent1].[Status] IN (N'N', N'P', N'P'))
```

It seems to be because it's comparing unicode with non unicode so it can't use the index on the Status column.

I've had similar problems before in other linq queries, but I thought they were solved by putting [Column(TypeName = "char")] on the property.

Does anyone know how I prevent SQL from putting those N's in front of all my Status values? I tried making statusList a List of char, but then I needed to change the definition of the Status column to char in code first, but that threw errors.

Thanks
David

Comment: This is the SQL being sent? EF does not send unparameterized queries. Are the parameters it sent varchar or nvarchar? Your display tool might have made a mistake.

Comment: I did type the generated SQL out by hand instead of copying, so there might be small mistakes, but it should be about right. From what I've seen when you do array.Contains(t.ColumnName) it doesn't create a parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you on .NET Framework 4? I think this was fixed in EF5 core libraries shipped with  .NET Framework 4.5. Here is a connect bug for this: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/709906/entity-framework-linq-provider-defaulting-to-unicode-when-translating-string-contains-to-like-clause The connect bug also contains a workaround - use EntityFunctions.AsNonUnicode() function to force strings not to be Unicode which may be helpful if you can't move to .NET Framework 4.5

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I am using .NET 4.0. I don't think the AsNonUnicode() workaround will work in my case. If I was doing **where t.Status.Contains("N")** then it would help, but I don't see how to do it for **statusList.Contains(t.Status)**. I might have to look into upgrading to EF5 to see if it's fixed there.

Comment: I installed .NET framework 4.5 and tried to upgrade the project to use 4.5, but it looks like you can't use .NET 4.5 from VS2010. I gave up upgrading to EF5, but the strange thing is my problem has gone away. It looks like installing .NET 4.5 alone fixed my problem. No more N's in the query. I don't know why.

Comment: That's true - you cannot use .NET Framework 4.5 with VS 2010. Since the fix for the issue in is .NET Framework 4.5 and .NET Framework is an in-place update installing the .NET Framework 4.5 itself will fix the issue (you will get other fixes as well)